# Copying Macro-Enabled Worksheet from One Workbook to Another 'Run-time error '1004''

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro that will allow me to drop this very commonly used worksheet directly into the files we need it in. It's a commonly used sheet that I'd like the ability to quickly and easily plop into existing documents to be copied and used frequently.

I am receiving: Run-time error '1004':Excel cannot access 'Junk'. The document may be read-only or encrypted.

This code is modified from another solution on stack overflow in order to be used globally on any document I wish. (that's the end goal here) Code below:

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim z As String
z = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Dim WS As Worksheet
Sheets.Add.Name = "Finance"

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("Desired worksheet file path")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(z)

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("Finance1").Range("A1:G12").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("Finance").Range("A1:G12").PasteSpecial

'Close x:
x.Close

End Sub
```

At the point of error both documents are open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveWorkbook.Path` gives the path of the activeworkbook, you should add the file to it. Like this:

`Set y = Workbooks.Open(z & "\fileSample.xlsx")`

There is one further options for an error - if the ActiveWorkbook is not saved, then it would not return anything. Thus, check it like this:
`If len(activeworkbook.path)>0 then`

Comment: Would this work for automation purposes: z = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

Comment: n = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Comment: Set y = Workbooks.Open(z & n)

Comment: @CodingNovice - the best way is to check it yourself. But it seems that it would, if you do not forget to save the file somewhere.

Comment: Checked and working. This does successfully avoid the file path issue. While I am still having trouble in that Workbooks.activate attempts to re-open the already open workbook, I will post that as another question.

Comment: @CodingNovice - glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Thec code would be like this.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim z As String, FileName1 As String, FileName2 As String

    z = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    FileName1 = "test1.xlsx"
    FileName1 = "test2.xlsx"
    '## Open both workbooks first:
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(z & FileName1)
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(z & FileName2)

    'Now, copy what you want from x:
    x.Sheets("Finance1").Range("A1:G12").Copy y.Sheets("Finance").Range("A1")

    x.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Would this be okay for my code?

z = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
n = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Dim WS As Worksheet
Sheets.Add.Name = "Finance"

'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("\\\\tehis6803\Wafer_Processing\Excel Macro, VBA & Immobile Documents\reference\Wafer Cost Analysis January2016.xlsm")
Set y = Workbooks.Open(z & n)

'Now, copy what you want from x:
x.Sheets("Finance1").Range("A1:G12").Copy

'Now, paste to y worksheet:
y.Sheets("Finance").Range("A1:G12").PasteSpecial

Comment: That didn't come out so well. I essentially added this: (z = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
n = ActiveWorkbook.Name)

Comment: As well as :Set y = Workbooks.Open(z & n)